# A misunderstanding with polymorphism and virtual destructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, delete-operator, virtual-destructor

Example:

```cpp
class Base {
  public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Base::~Base()\n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    void f() { }
    ~Derived() { std::cout << "Derived::~Derived()\n"; }
};

int main() {
  Base* p = new Derived();
  delete p;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Derived::~Derived()
Base::~Base()
```

I thought only the derived class destructor will be called since the pointed object to be freed is an instance of the derived class.

I have two questions:

1. Why was the virtual base destructor called?
2. Is it legally possible (or should it even be possible) to prevent the base class destructor from being called?

Comment: Basic rule doesn't matter if destructor is virtual or not. First destructor of current class is called, then destructors of fields of current class, then destructors of class ancestors (which apply same rule). It is just reversed order of construction.

Comment: This is how Inheritance works. A derived **is a** base.

Comment: `int main() { Derived d; return 0; }` will produce the same output. No, you cannot prevent the base destructor from running. Its job is to clean up the base object.

Comment: *Is it legally possible (or should it even be possible) to prevent the base class destructor from being called?* -- What would you be left with if only the derived portion is destroyed?  How would you then access this husk of an object if only a part of it gets destroyed?  What is the magic C++ syntax to retrieve this husk?  There isn't any, because as noted in the previous comment, that's how inheritance works.

Comment: *"I thought only the derived class destructor will be called since the pointed object to be freed is an instance of the derived class."* -- Do you think the same thing about constructors? That only the derived class constructor will be called since the newly allocated object is an instance of the derived class?

Answer (score 5):

> Why was the virtual base destructor called?

Because base class should be properly destructed. Derived class can not possibly do this.

> Is it legally possible (or should it even be possible) to prevent the
> base class destructor from being called?

No, because it would prevent properly destructing the base class (i.e. call it's members destructors)